# How to keep USB WiFi adapter from turning off/sleeping in Kali Linux VM?

Tags: network-adapter, kali-linux

I have an `Asus AC-56r 1300` which has a `rtl8812au` chipset. I am using Virtual box and got everything working (drivers, monitor mode, etc.).

However, when I try using Bridged connection, the adapter will work for a few minutes before entering sleep mode therefore disabling the internet connection and the light indicator on the adapter stops blinking.

In NAT mode it works perfectly as it is connected to the host and shares the internet (even when it is on sleep mode) but I need the IP address from Bridged connection. Is there any way on sharing the connection from Bridged with the host? Or perhaps prevent the USB adapter from entering sleep mode?

Comment: Found something weird today, when I switch the mode to "Monitor" mode, the blinking stops and stays on for a while before going back to blinking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "iw" command to set the power saving mode on or off. The syntax is `iw dev [interface] set power_save off` (you need to preface this with `sudo` if you aren't logged in as root).

Your interface is likely `wlan0`, but you can confirm this by running `ip link` and seeing what devices come up (because it's a WiFi interface, it should start with "wlan", "wlx", "wlp", or something similar depending on your configuration).

Comment: Ok so I tried the command with wlan0 which is the device, and it still turned off after a few minutes. I am thinking that this is something hardware related because when I connect it to windows; the lights stays on when connected to a WiFi connection. It says that it only supports windows and Mac but I've seen some people use this on Kali...